# When removing the StemEngraver, how can I ensure Lilypond properly places adjacent notes?

Tags: lilypond, engraving

The following code compiles without a hitch:

```
\version "2.20.0"

left = \relative c' {
  <b c g'>
}

\layout {
  \context {
    \Voice
      % When I uncomment below, the
      % note spacing goes awry
      %\remove "Stem_engraver"
  }
}

<<
    \new Staff \left
>>
```

[image]

However, when I `\remove` the `Stem_engraver`, the B and C are no longer properly spaced, but instead are stacked right on top of each other:

[image]

Is it possible to remove the Stem_engraver without sacrificing this note spacing? Because of the larger project of which this is a part, I'm hesitant to simply use `\hide Stem`, since some staves will have these stems and others will not.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I’d simply do `\override Stem.stencil = ##f` or `\omit Stem`. The problem here is that the `NoteHead` spacing relies on the direction of the stem. Of course it would be possible to implement a stemless version of this, but I do not think there would be much of a benefit (and definitely a benefit worth the effort).

Of course you could manually set `NoteHead.X-offset`.

Note that `\override Stem.stencil = ##f` and `\revert Stem.stencil` does offer the benefit that you can switch between Stem and no Stem within a Voice.